# S3 - Getting metadata from Post S3 Upload lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm generating a presigned URL using `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)` and for my params

```
var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: photoId + "-" + photoNumber + "-of-" + numberImages + ".jpeg",
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
    ContentType: contentType,
    Metadata : { testkey1 : "hello" }
};
```

I'm trying to receive the Metadata in my S3 successful upload lambda function, however it's not appearing. Anyone know why? The upload is successful and for my printed logs, I'm receiving everything but the metadata tag in the event:

`console.log(event);`

```
"Records": [
    {
        "eventVersion": "2.1",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventTime": "2020-01-15T06:51:57.171Z",
        "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": 
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": 
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "4C32689CE5B70A82",
            "x-amz-id-2": "AS0f97RHlLW2DF6tVfRwbTeoEpk2bEne/0LrWqHpLJRHY5GMBjy/NQOHqYAMhd2JjiiUcuw0nUTMJS8pDAch1Abc5xzzWVMv"
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "9a9a755e-e809-4dbf-abf8-3450aaa208ed",
            "bucket": {
                "name": ,
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": "A3SZPXLS03IWBG"
                },
                "arn": 
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "BcGMYe-1-of-1.jpeg",
                "size": 19371,
                "eTag": "45c719f2f6b5349cc360db9a13d0cee4",
                "sequencer": "005E1EB6921E08F7E4"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `s3` [event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html). the message structure originally doesn't contain metadata.

You need to get metadata in the `lambda` function in person.

You would get metadata through `s3` [head-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) command with the `bucket-name` and `object-key` in the event received.

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.2",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
         "eventTime":The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, when Amazon S3 finished processing the request,
         "eventName":"event-type",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-user-who-caused-the-event"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"ip-address-where-request-came-from"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"Amazon S3 generated request ID",
            "x-amz-id-2":"Amazon S3 host that processed the request"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"ID found in the bucket notification configuration",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"bucket-name",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"Amazon-customer-ID-of-the-bucket-owner"
               },
               "arn":"bucket-ARN"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"object-key",
               "size":object-size,
               "eTag":"object eTag",
               "versionId":"object version if bucket is versioning-enabled, otherwise null",
               "sequencer": "a string representation of a hexadecimal value used to determine event sequence, 
                   only used with PUTs and DELETEs"
            }
         },
         "glacierEventData": {
            "restoreEventData": {
               "lifecycleRestorationExpiryTime": "The time, in ISO-8601 format, for example, 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, of Restore Expiry",
               "lifecycleRestoreStorageClass": "Source storage class for restore"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: ```s3.headObject(params, function(err, data)``` worked for me